# With MUI and Styled Components, can I extend an object with a serialized style from the library's css method?

Tags: typescript, serialization, material-ui, styled-components, mixins

I'm using **MUI** 6 with **Styled Components**, importing both `styled` and `css` from `@mui/material/styles`.

If I write a SerializedStyled with the `css` method to use it as a mixin I get a `SerializedStyle`:

```
export const TextEllipse = (clamp: number) => css({
  /* CLAMP TEXT TO X LINES */
  "-webkit-box-orient": "vertical",
  "-webkit-line-clamp": clamp.toString(),

  display: "-webkit-box",
  overflow: "hidden",
  textOverflow: "ellipsis"
});
```

I can then use it as the return value of a `styled` function:

```
export const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)<
  TypographyProps & { clamp?: number }
>(({ clamp=1 }) => ( TextEllipse(clamp) ));
```

But if I need to add other styles to, well... mix in my styles the only way I can make it work is with string interpolation:

```
export const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)<
  TypographyProps & { clamp?: number }
>`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.primary?.main};
  ${({ clamp }) => TextEllipse(clamp!)}
`;
TitleTypography.defaultProps = { clamp: 1 };
```

In the project we're never using string interpolation to specify our styles and I would like to avoid telling my collegues "well, if you need mixins you have to use a completely different api".

**Is there a way to add a SerializedStyle to a styled return object without using string interpolation?** Something along these lines:

```
export const StyledTypography = styled(Typography)<
  TypographyProps & { clamp?: number }
>(({ clamp=1, theme }) => {
  const ellipseStyles = TextEllipse(clamp)
  return {
    color: theme.palette.primary?.main,
    >>> { ...ellipseStyles } <<<
  }
}
```